# Sessions in cloud applications dangerous?

Tags: django, session, cloud

We have a django app hosted on heroku. I had a situation:

1. A user entered an email in a form on page1. If the email existed in
   the database he was redirected to Login page otherwise to register
   page.
2. In the register page the form was filled with the same email
   entered on page1 using request.session that was populated previously.

**I was told it was dangerous as using sessions is not recommended in cloud applications. Is this notion correct both generally, and under above scenario?**

Comment: Who told you this, and did they tell you why it was not recommended?

Answer (score 2):

"Cloud application" is mainly a commercial buzz word but is, as far as I know not stricly defined. General definition could be "an application with a client on the end-user device, using online servers to do some processing or store somes data". But as a buzz word, in fact nearly all applications nowaday could be called "cloud application" if they use a server.

My point being your question could probably be "are server sessions safe ?".
And in this case the respond is yes, session aren't dangourous by themselves and storing data server side is as safe as your server is.

Comment: Agreed that "cloud application" may be so vague as to be useless.  Some would add that the servers in question are part of some big virtualized pool of infrastructure; but in many cases that can be true without using a cloud vendor or a true cloud model.    Cloud is basically lousy as an industry buzzword, the word itself lacks substance.